# Frechet derivative limit

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, calculus-of-variations, frechet-derivative

I was solving a problem by using the Frechet derivative to find the maximum. I result to the following limit

$$\lim_{||x||_{\mathbb{L}^2}\to 0}\frac{|f(x+t)-f(t)-J_{f(t)}(x)|_{\mathbb{R}}}{||x||_{\mathbb{L}^2}}=...=\underbrace{\lim_{||x||_{\mathbb{L}^2}\to 0}\frac{|\mathbb{E}(x^2)|_{\mathbb{R}}}{||x||_{\mathbb{L}^2}}}_{\text{why is this equal to $||x||_{\mathbb{L}^2}$}}=||x||_{\mathbb{L}^2}\to 0$$

where $f(\cdot):\mathbb{L}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $x\in\mathbb{L}^2$ and $\mathbb{E}()$ is the expected value operator. Can anyone explain why this limit equals $||x||_{\mathbb{L}^2}$? I am a little confused! I do not provide the function $f$ and the linear functional $J$ for simplicity since there is no interest, but the solution of the problem results to this outcome.

Comment: What are the  domain and range  of $f$?  Can you show a formula for $f$.  What is $\mathbb E$?

Comment: I have done it...

Comment: I am pretty sure you can answer this yourself. What is the definition of the $L^2$-norm and how does it relate to $\mathbb{E}$ ...? Btw, your actual question has nothing to do with Frechet derivatives.

Comment: $L^2-norm$ is a Banch space, specifically is the space of square integrable random varaibles. Well, yes, it does not have to do with Frechet derivatieves, but it was in the process to find the Frechet derivative. So, the question is, what is the relation between the expected value operator and the $\mathbb{L}^2$ space? Hmm it holds that $\mathbb{E}(x)=0$, and hence $\mathbb{E}(x^2)=\mathbb{V}ar(x)$...Is this related to the whole story?

Comment: Well, this is it! You are right. Since $\mathbb{E}(x^2)=\mathbb{V}ar(x)=||x||^2_{\mathbb{L}^2}$, then this outcome holds....isn,t it?